# Does the noun 'curb' have the meaning of the word 'bridle'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When I translate the 'curb' to my native language it translates to the verb similar to the word 'bridle'. But I can't understand whether the noun 'curb' has the meaning of 'bridle' in English or not.

So that's basically my question

Comment: What is the sense of the word that you're trying to translate? In the US, the word is mostly used to refer to the raised edge of a road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curb) gives one sense of "*curb*" as:

> (2b) a bit that exerts severe pressure on a horse's jaws;
> also : the chain or strap attached to it (See the illustration at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bit#art)

A "curb" so defined is not the same thing as a bridle, but is a related piece of equipment used with a horse. The term "curb-bit" is, I believe, sometimes used for this piece of equipment.

Some sources indicate that a "curb" (inn this sense) is **part** of a bit (or can be) and that a bit is or can be **part** of a bridle.

There are several other senses of "curb" that have little relation to this sense in current usage, although there is a relation in origin.

Comment: In the UK, 'curb' is typically a verb meaning 'limit or restrain', or a noun meaning 'a limit to something that is not wanted'. In the UK, also, the raised edge of a pavement or path is known as a 'kerb'. In American English, I believe, the spelling 'curb' is correct for all these.

Comment: @Michael Harvey all those senses and some others are correct, but none of them are, I think, highly relevant to this question, Because in both the UK and the US, "curb" can refer to a piece of equipment used on a horse. The connection is, I gather. that this equipment is used to **restrain** the horse. That sense of "restrain", I think, ultimately connects the other senses of this word.

Comment: It was just a spelling note in case anyone had wondered about the edges of pavements/sidewalks.

Answer (score 5):

### No, they're not synonymous in general use

The Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus lists "curb" as a synonym for the *archaic* noun "bridle":

> *archaic* **put a bridle on your tongue**: CURB, check, restraint, control.

A [curb bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curb_bit) (also called just a "curb") is also a part found in some bridles. While many people know what a bridle is, the word *curb* in this context is very niche and specialized. I would expect only people who are intimately familiar with horse accessories to know what it is (though it's included in my general-purpose dictionary, which means it's not entirely obscure).

Comment: I have encountered mentions of curbs and curb-bits as part of the equipment of a horse in novels, particularly historical novels, and fantasy fiction that deals with horses and their equipment, as well as some non-fiction works. Thus I know the word in that sense, even though I have never had much to do with horses in person.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I did a little volunteer work with horses and I never encountered it.

Comment: I think, but I am not sure, that most of the places I encountered the term were dealing with cavalry horses, and with methods no longer in current use.

Comment: Noting the point made by others, what happens if you ask for the translation of "kerb"?